# How can I integrate $\sqrt{\sin^2{2t}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How can I integrate  $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{\sin^2{2t}}~\mathrm{d}t$?

Comment: If $x\ge0$, then $\sqrt{x^2}=x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, and in turn
$$|x| = \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} -x & : & x < 0 \\ x & : & x \ge 0 \end{array}\right.$$
The integral you have can be written as
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\sin^22t}~\mathrm{d}t = \int_0^{\pi/2}\left| \sin 2t \right|~\mathrm{d}t$$
We have $\sin 2t \ge 0$ for all $0 \le t \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ and hence:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\left| \sin 2t \right|~\mathrm{d}t = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin 2t~\mathrm{d}t = \left[-\frac{1}{2}\cos 2t\right]_0^{\pi/2}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{\sin^22t}\,dt=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin2t\,dt=-\frac{1}{2}\cos2t|_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=-\frac{1}{2}(\cos(\pi)-\cos(0))=1$

Best.

Answer (score 1):

Since since $\sin(2t) \geq 0$ for all $t \in (0, \pi/2)$, we have $\sqrt{\sin^2(2t)} = \sin(2t)$. $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\sin^2(2t)}\,dt = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(2t)\,dt = -\frac 12\cos(2t)\Big|_0^{\pi/2}$$